# Does a character have to be casted to unsigned char before being compared to getc family returns?

Tags: c, language-lawyer, getchar, fgetc, getc

I am not sure about whether I have to cast a character to an `unsigned char` before being compared to the return of a `getc` family function.

The functions I consider `getc` family, are `getc`, `fgetc` and `getchar`

I am only talking about single-byte characters.

Here is example without the cast:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) // loop until newline or EOF
    putchar(c);

  return 0;
}
```

Here is an example with the cast:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
  int c;

  while ((c = getchar()) != (unsigned char)'\n' && c != EOF) // loop until newline or EOF
    putchar(c);

  return 0;
}
```

On the implementation I use, both work.

Is the cast required for portable programs?

I believe yes, because C11/N1570 7.21.7.1p2, emphasis mine:

> If the end-of-file indicator for the input stream pointed to by stream is not set and a next character is present, the fgetc function **obtains that character as an unsigned char** converted to an int and advances the associated file position indicator for the stream (if defined).

Comment: With a _character_ have to be casted ...", are you asking only about _narrow characters_?  .. and not wide nor UTF-8 characters?

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica Yeah, I should clarify I am only talking about narrow characters assuming that means "byte"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The C standard guarantees that character constants for these characters have nonnegative values:<sup>1</sup>

- the Latin alphabet letters, `A` to `Z` and `a` to `z`,
- the digits `0` to `9`,
- the graphic characters `!`, `"`, `#`, `%`, `&`, `’`, `(`, `)`, `*`, `+`, `,`, `-`, `.`, `/`, `:`, `;`, `<`, `=`, `>`, `?`, `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_`, `{`, `|`, `}`, and `~`,
- the space character, and
- control characters representing horizontal tab, vertical tab, form feed, alert, backspace, carriage return, and new line.

This follows from several sections of the C standard:

- 5.2.1 2 and 3 specify the characters of the basic execution character set.
- 6.2.5 3 says any character of the basic execution character set stored in a `char` is nonnegative.
- 6.4.4.4 10 says the value of a character constant, such as `'x'`, containing a single character (including a single character resulting from an escape sequence, like `'\n'`) is its value as a `char` converted to `int`.

The nonnegative `char` values are always a subset of the `unsigned char` values, so each character constant of one of these characters will have the same value as the value returned by `getc` when reading the same character.

If you need to handle other characters and cannot ensure those characters have nonnegative values in your target platforms, then you should convert the character constants to `unsigned char`.

### Footnote

<sup>1</sup> There is one pedantic exception to this which does not occur in practice. In a C implementation in which `char` and `int` are the same width and `char` is unsigned, `char` may have values not representable in `int`. In this case, the conversion is implementation-defined, so it may produce negative values. This conversion would be the same for converting the unsigned `char` value to `int` for the character constant and for converting the `unsigned char` `getc` return value to `int`, so they would produce the same value for the same characters. Conceivably, the conversion might be defined to clamp instead of wrap, which would make multiple characters map to the same value and be impossible to distinguish. This would be a defect in the C implementation, and there would not be a way to work around it using only the features fully specified by the C standard.

Comment: "The nonnegative `char` values are **always a subset** of the **`unsigned char`** values, so each character constant of one of these characters will have the same value as the value returned by `getc` when reading the same character." how does this stay true if `char` is unsigned?

Comment: @FFmpegEnthusiast: `char` and `unsigned char` are the same width (have the same number of bits). If `char` is unsigned, then `char` and `unsigned char` represent the same set of values. A set is a subset of itself.

Answer (score 2):

- `'\n'` is, in C, an `int`
- `getchar()` returns an `int`
- `c` is an `int`

You never need to cast an `int` to `int` so your first loop is what it should look like.

`EOF` expands to an integer constant expression, with type `int` and a negative value, so that it is impossible for it to conflict with a `char` (in the most common cases) that's cast to `unsigned char`. The most common value it has is `-1` which, if a successfully read `char` has the common range `[-128, 127]` and is cast to `unsigned char` gets the range `[0, 255]`, can not conflict.

There are exceptions, such as when the `char` based types have the same size as `int`. In that case, the added cast would still be pointless.

[C23](https://open-std.org/JTC1/SC22/WG14/www/docs/n3096.pdf) *7.23.7.6 The `getchar` function*:

> The `getchar` function returns the next character from the input stream pointed to by `stdin`. If the
> stream is at end-of-file, the end-of-file indicator for the stream is set and getchar returns `EOF`. If a
> read error occurs, the error indicator for the stream is set and getchar returns `EOF`.

Hence, you can still use `feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin)` to make the `EOF` check safely on such systems.

Regarding the value of `\n`:

Paragraph 6.2.5 (Types) in the C23 standard

> 3. An object declared as type `char` is large enough to store any member of the basic execution character set. If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a `char` object, its value is
>    **guaranteed to be nonnegative**. If any other character is stored in a `char` object, the resulting value is
>    implementation-defined but shall be within the range of values that can be represented in that type.

So, `'\n'` which is one of the characters in the basic execution character set can't be negative.

Comment: Corner exception: "`EOF` is selected so that it is impossible for it to conflict with a `char` that's cast to `unsigned char`." --> When `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, a conflict is possible.  Consider such graphic processors where all integer types are 64-bit.

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica True. Added exception

Comment: @chux-ReinstateMonica `EOF` is always negative. anything casted to an `unsigned char` is never negative which means that it is impossible for it to conflict.

Comment: @FFmpegEnthusiast When `UCHAR_MAX > INT_MAX`, comparing an `int` to an `unsigned char` becomes a `unsigned` to `unsigned` compare.  The `(unsigned) EOF` becomes a positive and collides with some `unsigned char`.

Comment: Nitpick: In order to do the `EOF` check on platforms on which `CHAR_MAX == INT_MAX`, it would be necessary to write `feof(stdin) || ferror(stdin)`. This is because on stream failure, `getchar` will also return `EOF`.

Comment: a much more common counter-example is `'\377'` that has the value `-1` on systems where `char` is signed by default and cannot be compared as a `char` value from the file.  The cast would indeed be necessary to match the return value of `getc()`: `if (c == (unsigned char)'\377') ...`

Comment: @chqrlie `'\n'` can't be negative though :)

Comment: The syllogism implied in this answer is incorrect. The fact that a character constant is an `int` and that you do not need to convert an `int` to an `int` is insufficient to guarantee the code is correct. It is also required as a premise that the character being compared has a nonnegative value.

Comment: That's right, but saying *`'\n'` is, in C, an `int`* is irrelevant, the important point is `'\n'` is not negative.

Answer (score 1):

The cast would be required if the character constant is negative because `getc()` returns byte values in the range of type `unsigned char` or the special negative value `EOF`, so negative character values are never returned by `getc()` actual bytes present in the file.

On an architecture where `char` is signed by default, character constants that represent characters that have a negative value, such as `\377` will have this negative value (with type `int`), thus `'\377'` has the value `-1` and would not match a byte in the file with all bits sets, but would match `EOF` mistakenly.

The C Standard specifies that all roman letters, digits, punctuation characters used for C operators and white space characters, including TAB, `'\n'` and other control characters are positive. Thus the newline character `'\n'` is positive and can be compared to `c` directly.  The `@` character used for email addresses is not in the list, so a perverse system that does not use ASCII might make this character negative and prevent `c == '@'` from matching successfully.

In your example, `(c = getchar()) != '\n'` is fully portable and does not require any cast.

Conversely, if you wish to match a non-breaking space `'\240'` (aka `'\xa0'`), the test `c == '\240'` would not work on systems where `char` is signed by default.  To write portable code, you must indeed cast the character constant as `(unsigned char)` for such values:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int c;

    while ((c = getchar()) != EOF) {
        if (c == (unsigned char)'\240') {
            printf("NBSP found\n");
        }
        if (c == (unsigned char)'\377') {
            printf("0xFF found\n");
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When the character constant is positive or 0, (such as `'\n'` which is *always* positive <sup>*1</sup>) the cast is not needed.

When the character constant is [negative](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77908667/does-a-character-have-to-be-casted-to-unsigned-char-before-being-compared-to-get/77908730?noredirect=1#comment137350056_77908731), a cast is useful depending on coding goals.

---

<sup>*1</sup>  [§6.2.5 ¶3 sentence 2](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.2.5p3) of the ISO C11 standard states the following: "If a member of the basic execution character set is stored in a char object, its value is guaranteed to be nonnegative." [§5.2.1](http://port70.net/%7Ensz/c/c11/n1570.html#5.2.1) defines the basic execution character set to include the newline character.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to make a cast, as the character `\n` has a positive value either considered `signed char` or `unsigned char`.   The conversion will convert `unsigned char` first to `unsigned int` leading all characters in the range [0..255] that will never compare equal to `EOF` --which has a negative value as `int`--  in the case of `signed char` to `int` conversion the character will be converted to `int` (this will result in U.B. for negative values, but normally this means sign extension of the sign bit, and there's a chance that the input value `\377` to be converted into -1, makint the comparison with `EOF` to give fake results) and will do the comparison as `int`.

As I say, *in this special case* you don't need to make the explicit cast to `unsigned`, as the character to be converted will be `'\n'` which is positive.  Conversions from `signed` to `unsigned` are first made if done automatically, and then the bit extension takes place, so you finally, must be a bit careful.